# Bug on the javascript to retrieve data from a Quick View CRM 2015 Rollup 1

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have trouble retrieving a value from a Quick View (as per quick view i mean show the related entity details in a parent entity, eg. primary contact email address on the account).

The usual way to retrieve those is by the sdk syntax:

```
    Xrm.Page.getControl("contactQuickForm_contactQuickForm_contact_mobilephone");
```

I tried this approach but now the result is an empty control. Anyone had a chance to see this defect in the new rollup? I troubleshoot a little around it, including removing all the controls from the page and scroll through the list to confirm that the control wasn't actually there and i wasn't making any syntax errors.

Comment: So, control is *not* included in `Xrm.Page.controls.get()`, do I understand correctly ?

Comment: Is this even supported?

Comment: @JamesWood yes (see the 'remarks' here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_getAttribute)

Comment: Yes it is supported and is still in the documentation of the sdk for rollup 1 (i chekced if maybe they decided to do it in a different way), the control is not there anymore @Alex you are correct. Can anyone else confirm that is not working in rollup 1?